# How can i connect my private blockchain network with public ERC20 token?

Tags: tokens, private-blockchain

I have setted up a private blockchain network which is running in my server. I am ok with the process of creating smart contracts. We have to create a token that can be available in exchanges.

**Question 1:**
Can i connect with main network token using my private blockchain network?

**Question 2:**
How can i manage the token's transaction process with my private blockchain network?

Answer (score 1):

- **Question 1 : Can i connect with main network token using my private blockchain network?**

  No. Currently, different chains are not able to interconnect directly. You would need a middleware to handle that (like a nodeJS server with web3js).
- **Question 2: How can i manage the token's transaction process with my
  private blockchain network?**

I don't really understand what you mean. Transaction are handled by the chain itself. But from my point of view, if people can buy tokens on your **PRIVATE CHAIN** , you will need to assign them an address. There are several javascript librairies that can do that.
You would also need a user interface to show the balance tu the user.

Note: ICO (are you an other scam? Please don't tell me you have a white paper...) are not very "good" on private chain, because the token is worth nothing and not tradable with token exchanges. If you really want do build a **PUBLIC token**, just do it on main net.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andromelus. As i'm new to the ethereum, blockchain i have mentioned ICO with my knowledge and i have removed it, seems it's a bad thing!! Ok, fine. So it is possible to interact with main network tokens with the help of middlewares. Correct me if i am wrong, i will create a new token in main network and i am connecting it through middleware to my private network. I can do token transfer in my private network that will impact on the main network token count. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. This is not related to ethereum but to your software logic. If something happens somewhere, you can trigger something else somewhere else. However, I have been working this topic for a while, and honestly, there is nothing good in doing that because there is data redundancy and having a server handling that would be costly (+ the logic might be complicated)